# Reference token management

Tags: identityserver4, access-token

Reference token as an identifier to the access token stored in identity server. What is the best practice to manage it?

1. There was a claim changed, how to update the access token to reflect
   the change. I found that the current access token doesn't get updated automatically for that case so would like to know how to achieve that claim update on the access token.
2. What is the suitable lifetime it should have (15 days or more?), once expired to
   re-issue it with a refresh token or just getting the end user to
   login again?
3. Does it need to be validated through the introspection endpoint from
   the javascript client (Angular) at all? I know the API needs to have a back
   channel to validate it just unsure about the javascript side.

Answer (score 0):

To get automatic refresh token management, I would recommend that you use the [IdentityModel library](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) from the authors of IdentityServer.

You can set the UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh flag to true in the client definition, then you will get updated claims when you refresh the access token.

For dealing with tokens in the browser, I would recommend watchin this video
[alert‘OAuth 2 0’; // The impact of XSS on OAuth 2 0 in SPAs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw&ab_channel=PhilippeDeRyck)
then visit the [Backend for Frontend (BFF) Security Framework library](https://duendesoftware.com/products/bff).

Comment: Thanks for the infor! Reference token as an identifier I can't check its expiry as itself doesn't contain claim infor, my question is how to renew it when its associated access token is expired? Do the renewal on the Angular app or IdentityServer side?

Comment: Say the access token is expired before the renewal process starts, that could happen as the user is not active for a while and it doesn't trigger the refresh token to renew the access token on the backend. What will happen - can it be renewed with an expired access token to trigger the refresh token renewal process for a new access token?

Comment: You can keep track of the expiretime of the current access token in the client (you receive that as separate parameter when you do a refresh) and if it is a about to expire or it is expired you do the refresh cycle. Alternatively you can just keep using the access token, and if it fails, you refresh it and try again.  There are different approaches for dealing with this.